# NumPy array IndexError: index 99 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using Python 3.6 and I got a index error when I try to use NumPy array reference.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

length1 = 35
length2 = 20
siglength = 10

csrf = np.array([])

sm = 2.0 / 35
sm2 = 2.0 / 20

for n in range(0, 198) :

    if n == 0 :
        i = 100
        t = i - 100
        setcsf = t - 0 * sm + 0
        csrf = np.append(csrf, setcsf)

    else :
        i = (close[n] / close[int(n+1)]) * 100
        t = i - 100
        setcsf = t - csrf[int(i-1)] * sm + csrf[int(i-1)]
        csrf = np.append(csrf, setcsf)
print(csrf)
```

But the result is:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "test.py", line 64, in <module>
> setcsf = t - csrf[int(i-1)] * sm + csrf[int(i-1)]
> IndexError: index 99 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
> ```

I think the problem is line 64 `setcsf = t - csrf[int(i-1)] * sm + csrf[int(i-1)]`, but I definitely don't know how to modify the code and replace it.

Comment: Your code snippet is not complete since you do not show any definition for the name `close`. Please complete your code and make it run-able resulting in the error you show. Your error references a `line 64` but there is no such line number in your code. In other words, read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error is due to your line

```
setcsf = t - csrf[int(i-1)] * sm + csrf[int(i-1)]
```

The error message

> ```
> IndexError: index 99 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
> ```

says you tried to access index 99 (`int(i-1)` has value 99) of `csrf` on axis 0 (its only axis) when it only has a size of 1, so the only index you could have accessed would be 0.

Additionally, your example code is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where does variable `close` come from?

Maybe you want to use `n` instead of `i` like in the following line?

```
setcsf = t - csrf[int(n-1)] * sm + csrf[int(n-1)]
```

That would make sense, since `n-1` will always reference the index of the former loop run. You wouldn't get `IndexError`.

Or maybe you want to initialize `csrf` with values beforehand?

```
csrf = np.array([0] * 198)
```